# Facebook create an album graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have written a facebook app which checks if an album exists, if it does not it creates one.

This was all working 2 weeks ago and now I go and check it to show the client and it is no longer working. I was thinking it could have something to do with Facebook and maybe they now require an SSL? I can't find any evidence of this on there website however.

The error I am getting is:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/517578134925015/albums?access_token=AAAD5tUCp808BAIZBPk4eV11mlf9C92velLsDeZAm5mXhKZCkwpM3LNy7ax6BBmhuH4BVZBUN6Iycyt55NoXZAFSts9zHeCFNzT6FLJYucgT2SQG8fOYIP) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in /var/www/vhosts/hidden/development/cms/backend/publishAlbum.php on line 59
```

My current code is:

```
                //If no album ID is set, create a new album.
            $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$pageId."/albums?" . "access_token=". $pageAccessToken;
            $postdata = http_build_query(
                array(
                    'name' => $albumName
                )
            );
            $opts = array('http' =>
                array(
                    'method'=> 'POST',
                    'header'=>
                    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => $postdata
                )
            );
            $context = stream_context_create($opts);
            $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, $context));
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

The code I tried that uses the API.

```
$params = array(
    'name' => 'testtest',
    'message' => 'test test'
);
try{
    $albumtResult = $facebook->api('/'.$pageId.'/albums', 'post', $params);
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    error_log($e);
    $albumtResult = null;
}
$albumId = $albumtResult->id;
```

Here is the caught exception: http://pastebin.com/pxeyRTDn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, someone created a bug report on Facebook that was almost identical to my problem.

Since being created it has had a lot of repo's and other people reporting that they are also having the same issue.

The priority on facebook has been changed to high so hopefully it gets fixed soon.

Facebook bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/376442565760536?browse=search_50361119879b15494037772

Thanks for everyones time.

Comment: You have to wait 24hours, only 2 hours left.

Comment: This has been fixed. It was tested and working on the 31/08/2012.

Comment: has this problem been fixed?  I am still having this problem when I use Graph API

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason for this error would be much easier to figure out, if you’d used the PHP SDK to make API calls, instead of doing them “by hand“ using file_get_contents … because using the SDK, you get an exception that should point to the error cause, whereas file_get_contents (by default) just throws a warning when it gets anything else than a 2xx HTTP status code for an answer, and does not let you access the response body (which will most likely contain a human-readable error message as well).

My advice: **Use the SDK!**

Otherwise, add to the context parameter that you want to see the returned data even if the status code signals an error. (details -> see manual)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is how I done it in the first place, but that does not work either. This way, worked up until a few weeks ago.

I have added the code to the original post that I wrote using the API, maybe you could tell me if there is something wrong with it. Although, I believe it should work.

Comment: OK, _“An unknown error has occurred.”_ is not the most helpful error description (thanks, Facebook), but the type of _OAuthException_ could mean that it’s a permissions problem …(?)

Comment: I thought it could be permissions, but my app is meant to check if album is there, if its not create it and then upload a batch of images using the batch request. 

But at the moment, it fails to create the album with OAuthException error and uploads all the images into a default gallery with the name of the app.

So I should have the correct permissions to create an album if it can upload images.